# Can observations in R be removed along with subsequent data in its row through the use of subset?

Tags: r, subset

Here is an example of the data frame I'm working on [the data frame is actually (189x11)]:

```
   >WB
       ID AGE LWT RACE SMOKE PTL HT UI FVT  BWT LOW
       85  19 182    2     0   0  0  1   0 2523   0
       86  33 155    3     0   0  0  0   3 2551   0
       87  20 105    1     1   0  0  0   1 2557   0
       88  21 108    1     1   0  0  1   2 2594   0
```

Now through use of subset I want to create a subsettted dataframe that would contain a table for women whom smoked during pregnancy and vice versa, which i want to look like this:

```
      >smoke 
       ID AGE LWT RACE SMOKE PTL HT UI FVT  BWT LOW
       87  20 105    1     1   0  0  0   1 2557   0
       88  21 108    1     1   0  0  1   2 2594   0
```

and

```
       >nonsmoke
       ID AGE LWT RACE SMOKE PTL HT UI FVT  BWT LOW
       85  19 182    2     0   0  0  1   0 2523   0
       86  33 155    3     0   0  0  0   3 2551   0
```

However, when I use subset:

```
    smoke <-subset(dategrame,SMOKE==1)
```

I get this:

```
      ID AGE LWT RACE SMOKE PTL HT UI FVT  BWT LOW
       85  19 182    2     1   0  0  1   0 2523   0
       86  33 155    3     1   0  0  0   3 2551   0
       87  20 105    1     1   0  0  0   1 2557   0
       88  21 108    1     1   0  0  1   2 2594   0
```

So could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and why can't i get the dataframes I want? Because I'm trying separate them like that so I can compare the BWT of the mothers whom smoked and didn't smoke through a boxplot.

Comment: You could just do `split(df, df$SMOKE)`.  Then you have the two data frames in a list

Comment: I tried that and it still did the same thing. However, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to subset the dataframe if you want to make a boxplot plot like that. Try this:

```
d = data.frame(SMOKE=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), BWT=c(2523,2551,2560,2557,2594,2600))
boxplot(d$BWT ~ d$SMOKE)
```

[image]

Comment: Well I know through the use of boxplot(d$BWT ~ d$SMOKE) I could create a boxplot like that, but at the same time I thought if I created separate dataframes for smoking and non-smoking it would be easier to compare the data in terms of like avg BWT between smoking and non-smoking, ect. Is there no way to create a dataframe like the way I want?

Comment: check Richard's comment to your question above where he uses `split`